# Fusion tables customize map info windows: list names with same lat/long

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

hi fusion table enthusiasts,
help?

I've built a google form that feeds into a fusion table where different individuals may opt to nominate onto the map, but have the same lat/long (e.g. individuals from the same office). Is there a way in fusion tables to customise the map info window to list the names (rows in the spreadsheet) with the same lat/long? I don't want to change the lat/long (we tried that but it didn't work).

I searched stack overflow and maybe this might be relevant? 
[Google Maps API - Display info for all markers with same lat/long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794219/google-maps-api-display-info-for-all-markers-with-same-lat-long)

any help/advice will be greatly appreciated,
kind regards
Anna

Comment: What's the goal? What is supposed to show on the map? What is supposed to show in the infowindow? What have you tried?

Comment: thank you MrUpsidown. The goal is to map people within offices across the state who are interested in an activity. There is a google form they fill in (selecting location and interests from drop downs within the form) and it feeds into a fusion table, which is then mapped and put on our intranet. So a staff member may be interested in another location, they click on it and see a list of names of peers and their interests (which they've filled in via the google form).

Comment: The problem is - multiple staff may be in the same location, and currently only the first named person appears. Ideally, the infowindow would have a list of name and research interests (two columns of the fusion table) per location. I've got it all nearly there, I just need to figure out how to create a list within an infowindow

Comment: another thought was that I could group names within a location cell, but that requires manual entry as far as I can see. There's about 44 locations. I'm a hack, but have successfully used fusion tables before, but this I can't figure out! Any help or advice will be appreciated, kind regards, Anna